# Accessing specific array based on key in ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

```
<button *ngFor="let item of items[category]"> </button>
```

Where `items: { cat1: [], cat2: [] }`.
I need category to be a string variable to access the two arrays in items.
How do i tackle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
         <button *ngFor="let item of items[category]" > {{item}}</button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  items: any =  { cat1: ['cat1','cat2'], cat2: ['peter','peter2'] };
  category = 'cat1';
  constructor() {
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

plunkr working:

https://plnkr.co/edit/w1YJeZPAMwN5WP3uVhZ7

Comment: I was using what you are doing, but my key was "cat" and i was trying with "Cat" and i could not figure what the hell was going wrong!
Anyway i will accept your answer because it is correct.